# In SpriteKit, make arrow follow target once it hit it

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

My game has a target which moved from right to left, once an arrow hit it they should move along together from right to left. I was able to make it work but it's not perfect - the arrow is kind of shaking in the target and it sometimes goes off the screen. I believe that its related to the frame rate but I am not sure how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
func arrowCollideWithTarget() {
    arrows.last!.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    let followAction = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: TimeInterval(Int.max)) {
        node, elapsedTime in

        node.position.x += (self.targetLocation?.x)! - (self.latestTargetLocation?.x)!
    }

    arrows.last!.run(followAction)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution, `move(toParent)`

```
arrows.last!.move(toParent:target)
```

Now no actions are needed, and move(toParent) changes the position of arrow to match that of where it is at in the targets coordinate system, so no need to translate the arrow either.

Basically, this works exactly how you would think in real life.

When the arrow hits the target, you expect the arrow to become a "child" of that target.  So if you took the target, and moved it to a new wall, the arrow would go with it because the arrow is attached to the target.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But it changed the size of the arrow (the height of it dropped and it made it thicker), do you know why?

Comment: i am not going to play this game with you.  You know the problem, your arrow is changing size.  Find everywhere you are manipulating the size of things, and play around till you find the root cause.

Comment: Will do. Thank you! Appreciate the help!

Comment: I found the problem. The size of the target is different than the size of previous arrow parent. When you move a sprite  to a different parent who has a different size the size of that sprite also changes. I am now looking at how can I prevent the arrow from changing its size when it moves to a smaller parent. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Any idea why when collision occur at the bottom edges it place the arrow as if it did not collide with the target at all (about ~pixels below the target)?